# Active Directory explorer - How can I search if a Group 'contains' a user?

Tags: active-directory, explorer

In my Active Directory there is a Group "Gruppo Pippo", whit the attribute 'member'.
'member' contains many 'users':

CN=Alba Albi,OU=Developers,OU=Users,...

CN=Bianca Bianchi,OU=Partners,OU=Users,...

CN=Carlo Pony,OU=Developers,OU=Users,...

CN=Duilio Dorati,OU=Developers,OU=Users,...

I need a search that tell me if a user is contained in "gruppo Pippo".

I tried

(&(distinguishedName=CN=Gruppo Pippo,OU=DevOps,OU=Applications,OU=Groups,OU=Organization)(member=*Pony*))

but the operator 'contains': 'member contains Pony' doesn't run. (see image). Any suggestion? Thanks.

[The search on AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCjV9.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The `member=` filter is incorrect. The value needs to be the value in the multivalued attribute, the distinguished name.

`member="CN=Carlo Pony,OU=Developers,OU=Users,..."`

Comment: Thank you Greg, you're right.  I mispelled the answer (now it is correct).  I know only the surname of the user, not the entire distinguished_name, and I would find if the surname is contained in the attribute 'member' of the group 'CN=Gruppo Pippo,OU=DevOps,OU=Applications,OU=Groups,OU=Organization'.  If you see the image it is clearer.  Thanks.